# JavaFX получение текста изTextField в UTF-8

Tags: java, javafx

Стоит задача получить JSON с сервера по ссылке, часть которой формируется в TextField. Но при вызове `TextField.getText()` русский текст, который нельзя заменить английским, выглядит примерно так: `���������`. Даже если выводить текст так: `System.out.println(cityField.getText());` результат тот-же. Явно проблема с кодировкой, гугление результата не дало. 
Благодарю заранее

Comment: Кодировка консоли у вас тоже UTF-8?

Comment: intelliJ IDEA project Encoding стоит в UTF-8

Comment: Как получаете данные с сервера? Я предполагаю, что при получении данных с сервера данные декодируются неправильной кодировкой.